# Why must "aurelia-cli" depend on the "npm" package?

Tags: aurelia

The npm package itself is pretty cumbersome.
Is there any particular reason why we have to depend on it?

Comment: I think that questions like that belong in the [github project](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues).

Comment: @avrahamcool https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/914